# Is it possible to test if some page has facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have authorized Facebook app, that is, ability to use FQL.

I have to know if some url in the internets have facebook like button. I've read the [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and don't find anything that helps me. Have I missed something?

Comment: Refer to this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Thank you, bit my need is not to build a button, but test if some page has this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to scrape the page and look for the related Facebook tags. Another thing that *may* work is checking the page against the Facebook graph end-point like so (example [1](http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.masteringapi.com/) - [2](http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/)):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_URL_HERE
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.masteringapi.com/
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/
```

If fields like `likes` or `shares` is present then maybe a like button is there. Yet that also could mean that someone just posted the link on Facebook.